# trying to publish to app store - No provisioned iOS device is connected

Tags: iphone, app-store

Hi
I do not wish to start the iphone app executable on the device.
I just want to publish it to appstore.
so after following all steps I have in my folder:

MyAppName.app.dSYM

However from what I understood this is not enough i need to zip the app file... if I could zip this file and upload it to app store this would be great.  But when I tried the application loader it didn't accept a zip with this file.

so in xcode I have choosen: device and not simulator, and it complains now when I build that the device is not connected (the device is not with me...) so my question is can I create (build) the the product.app so that I can then publish it to app store even when I don't have a device with me?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your App Store provisioning profile setup and selected, under the **Build** menu select **Build and Archive** it sounds like you are doing **Build and Run** (which is not what you want).

Then from the organiser you can **Submit** directly to the App Store, you don't even need application loader.

Hope this helps,
Oli

Comment: Note that you do have to connect a device to do "Build and Archive".

Comment: You definitely do NOT have to connect a device to do "Build and Archive" I just tested it.